Mudblazor Datagrid aggregations are not aligned with parent column
I recently upgraded Mudblazor version from 7.15.0 to 8.0.0-preview.6 and then in all components  where Data grid was used, aggregation part was shifted.so I had to downgrade to previous version. A picture is attached To clarify the problem. deployed in VS 2022 version 17.12.3 .Net9 , direction is RTL Persian.
any suggestion welcome.
aggregations are not aligned with parent columns

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
